# AttributedText.boundingRectWithSize: Space was omitted when start a new line in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView, whose bounds changes according to the Input and the text font. Everything works fine when I have one line in TextView, but when I start a new line by press "return" on keyboard, something strange happened:

1. Space at the end of first line was omitted
2. When the length of new line is equal to first line, input Space
   doesn't change the bounds(TextView did receive the word). However,
   any other characters work fine.

Here is my Code:

```
let attributedText = labelView.attributedText

let recSize = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max, CGFloat.max), options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading], context: nil)
```

`recSize` didn't change when I input Space in the condition I mentioned above.

I also tracked the `attributedText`, the attributedText did change.

```
What
What        {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fac23128480> font-family: \"Baskerville-BoldItalic\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 65.13pt";
}
```

How could I fix the it ?

Comment: use fixed value for "boundingRectWithSize" maximum width size instead "CGFloat.max" i.e "CGSizeMake(textView.width, CGFloat.max)".

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran This doesn't work for me

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran Hmm..Just tried a App which provides the similar function, I found it also has the problem. May be boundingRectWithSize can't handle lineBreak automatically.....quite annoying.